# MD5 Encrypting Woes

Tags: python, encryption, md5

I've written an encrypting program in Python, one of my options is an md5 encryption. When i run a known string through my md5 encryption I receive a different hash value then if I run the EXACT same string through an md5 encryption website or cryptofox for firefox.

eg. my programs hash output - `fe9c25d61e56054ea87703e30c672d91` - plaintext: `g4m3`

eg. online hash / cryptofox - `26e4477a0fa9cb24675379331dba9c84` - plaintext: `g4m3`

EXACT same word, 2 different hash values.
now heres my code snipet:

```
word="g4m3"
string=md5.new(word).hexdigest()
print string
```

Comment: Note that MD5 is a hashing mechanism, not an encryption mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You included a newline in your MD5 input string:

```
>>> import md5
>>> word="g4m3"
>>> md5.new(word).hexdigest()        # no newline
'26e4477a0fa9cb24675379331dba9c84'
>>> md5.new(word + '\n').hexdigest() # with a newline
'fe9c25d61e56054ea87703e30c672d91'
```

When reading data from a file, make sure you remove the newline character at the end of the lines. You can use `.rstrip('\n')` to just remove line separation characters from the end of the line, or use `.strip()` to remove *all* whitespace from start or end of the line:

```
>>> word = 'g4m3\n'
>>> md5.new(word).hexdigest()
'fe9c25d61e56054ea87703e30c672d91'
>>> word = word.strip()
>>> md5.new(word).hexdigest()
'26e4477a0fa9cb24675379331dba9c84'
```

Comment: hmm, ive got word.strip('\r'\n') after word (its actually part of a much larger script, ive just thrown in the snippet) would that remove the newline? or am i missing something else? the entire code is posted at http://hastebin.com/micoluyoni.tex if you want to take a look. im using option 2 from my list just to test my m5d code because if its wrong there... its wrong everywhere in my code

Comment: @L8NIT3TR0UBL3: No need to strip `\r` here, Python normalises text files to use `\n` for newlines on all platforms.

Comment: @L8NIT3TR0UBL3 as a separate point, "\r\n" would also be treated as a separate character, thereby changing your hash further.  I don't know much about python, but I would go with Martijn's advice above

Comment: @L8NIT3TR0UBL3: You need to *assign* the return value of `.strip()`. Strings are not mutable, so `word.strip()` just does nothing. Use `word = word.strip()` instead.

Comment: PERFECT!! i wil give that a try!! thanks so much! thats exactly why i came to this site with my issue, a whole bunch of super fast, knowledgable answers!!

Answer (score 3):

As to your question: Hashing is very sensitive.  Even a single character of difference can result in a radically different output string.  It may be the case that the online implementation is appending a whitespace char, or more likely, a newline.  This extra character will change the output of the algorithm.  (It's also possible the opposite is happening: you are appending a newline and the online one is not)

As to MD5 "encryption": 
MD5 is **NOT** encryption.  It is **hashing**.  Encryption takes in data and a key, and spits out random data.  This data is recoverable.  Hashing, on the other hand, takes in data and spits out a finite amount of data that REPRESENTS the original data.  The original data, however, unless stored elsewhere, is lost.

More information for reference:
Another interesting difference is the data the various types of algorithms spit out.  Encryption can take in any amount of data (within the scope of the OS/software of course) and will output a bunch of data appx. equal in size to the input data.  Hashing, however, will not.  Since it is a mere representation of the data, it has a limited output.  This can pose problems.  For instance, if you had an infinite amount of data, eventually, two entirely different pieces of data would have the same hash.  For this reason, when using hashing to compare two different values, it is usually a good idea to compare two separate hashes as well.  The statistical probability that two separate pieces of data having TWO EQUAL HASHES is astronomically low.

Of course, then you get into hashing algorithms that utilize encryption methods at their core, but I won't go into that here.

Comment: And MD5 is technically a cryptographic hash, which is usually where the confusion comes from.

Comment: @MartijnPieters oh i agree.  On both points.  Which is why I added much more to the answer

Comment: It's slightly better now; you may want to move the rant to the bottom to focus on the answer. :-)

Comment: I apologize for misusing "encryption" i did realize that md5 is a hashing algo which is entirely different, but the explanation was definately great as i didnt quite know WHAT the difference actually was.

Comment: @L8NIT3TR0UBL3: I've added more information on hashing/encryption if you're interested.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I believe this answer does address the question in the first paragraph. The rest is gravy.

Comment: @NullUserException: It does *now*; it has seen some editing. :-) Removed my outdated comment.

Comment: A couple minor points: encryption doesn't spit out "random" data. Encryption algorithms are deterministic and will spit out the same *random looking* data if the input (plaintext, key, and IV - if an IV exists) is the same. And the chances of a large enough collision resistant hash function colliding on two inputs are low enough that using two algorithms is a waste of time. Unless the inputs were intentionally manipulated to generate a collision in hash functions with "broken" collision-resistance, you can assume you're safe.